# Sharing a LinkedBlockingQueue between Container Managed Threads

Tags: queue, cdi, jndi, java-ee-7, wildfly-10

I have an application, where I have some Producer Threads which need an Input Queue and a Buffer. The Buffer has an Observer, that empties the buffer once it reached a certain limit and puts batches on another Queue2. Queue2 then is read by a consumer which writes the batches.

Currently what I'm lacking in my program achitecture is a neat way to get these Queues and Buffer into the Runnables, without doing Constructor magic or Setter.

I cannot use @Inject, since the CDI Context is not propagated to the subthreads. One could implement his own context, that does things similar to the ApplicationScopedContext, but currently I'm not willing to do this (if someone has a good implementation example please let me know).

Since the JNDI Tree is propagated to the Subthreads I thought about using it, but I fear the Serialization, which is definitely not what I want with Queues.

So my question is: Are Objects that are bound into the JNDI Tree in Wildfly 10 References or are they Serialized?

Comment: Why not use JMS?

Comment: Because JMS does not seem to have the ability to create blocking Queues. The BlockingQueues are a mean of limiting the flow of data between the Threads. Also the problem with JMS might be, that the application spawns WorkUnits that need there own queue, since the work they do is specific.

Comment: Ok, sorry. I should have prepended the previous comment with: _"It sounds like you are trying to make a simple local technology more advanced with running into the first problem and maybe later to new ones...."_ And then the previous comment and after that I should have added _"Or any other serious queuing technology with scaling/distribution/clustering/etc"_ ;-) There are lots of them already (including ones with blocking but iirc, JMS has this too)

Comment: What do you mean by "I cannot use @Inject, since the CDI Context is not propagated to the subthreads."? If the server is managing the threads, e.g. a `ManagedExecutorService`, then the context is propagated.

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins no this is not the case hence my Question. Scopes are bound to Threads as per CDI Spec, so my Custom Scope is not propagated!

Comment: Check https://github.com/tomitribe/microscoped. There are some custom scopes and a core ScopeContext that You can reuse/extend for Your needs. What You need for custom scope to work is basically activate it in every thread You run (assuming that BeanManager is available in these threads).